# Is this a bug in resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper, ienumerable

I have me some Resharper squiggles here.

[image]

and they tell me that I have a **possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable** going on. However you can see that this is not true. **final** is explicitly declared as a list ( `List<Point2D>` ) and **pointTangents** is declared previously as  `List<PointVector2D>`

Any idea on why Resharper might be telling me this?

**Edit Experiments To See If I can replicate with simpler code**

As you can see below there are no squiggles and no warnings even though Bar is declared to take IEnumerable as arg.

[image]

Comment: what type is `pointTangents`? where is that coming from?

Comment: The question says that it is a list. List<Point2D> to be precise. Not IEnumerable<Point2D> which is why resharper should not be giving this warning.

Comment: show more of your code - could it be passed in as `IEnumerable`?

Comment: why don't you calculate the first/last on your own?

Comment: @DanielA.White Because the implementation of First() is smart and if it is a list then it uses  this[0]. Same goes with Last(). Anyway the question is not about micro-optimising the code.

Comment: `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` and the LINQ extensions you use, are defined on `IEnumerable<T>` so that might be triggering R#'s warning.

Comment: @DanielA.White It shouldn't matter what it is passed in as. It is a List and resharper is not meant to give this warning for lists.

Comment: if its being passed as `IEnumerable` in this scope thats why.

Comment: and as for computing it yourself, to me it would help with readability and maintainability.

Comment: @DanielA.White ``pointTangents.Last()`` is more maintainable, safer and readable than ``pointTangents[pointTangents.Count-1]`` And I'm not sure what you mean ''being passed in as an IEnumerable" You can't just assign an IEnumerable to a List without an explicit cast.

Comment: @DanielA.White but to satisfy your curiosity. ```List<PointVector2D> pointTangents = interp.Select(p => p.t.FastRotateAroundZ(Math.PI/2, p.t)).ToList();
``` is the assignment to __pointTangents__ and is in the same scope as all the warnings.

Comment: You move your mouse over the 2 highlighted types and they are both List<T> in that scope? If yes, looks like a Resharper bug.

Comment: RS 9.1.1 in VS2012; similar code referencing a List<T>; no squiggly line.

Comment: I've played around with my code and subtle changes seem to make the warning flick on or off. Pretty sure now it's a resharper false positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks a lot like [RSRP-429474 False-positive warning for possible multiple enumeration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-429474) :

> I have this code:
>
> ```
> List<string> duplicateLabelsList = allResourcesLookup.SelectMany(x => x).Select(x => x.LoaderOptions.Label).Duplicates<string, string>().ToList(); ; 
> if (duplicateLabelsList.Any()) 
> throw new DuplicateResourceLoaderLabelsException(duplicateLabelsList);
> ```
>
> For both usages of duplicateLabelsList, I'm being warned about
>   possible multiple enumeration, despite the fact I've called ToList and
>   therefore there should be no multiple enumeration.

which (currently) has a Fix Version of 9.2, which (currently) isn't yet released.

Answer (score -1):

The extension method

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);
```

is defined for the type `IEnumerable<TSource>`.

If one looks at the implementation of `Last<TSource>`:

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null)
    {
         int count = list.Count;
         if (count > 0) return list[count - 1];
    }
    else
    {
         using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) 
         {
              if (e.MoveNext())
              {
                    TSource result;
               
                    do
                    {
                       result = e.Current;
                    } while (e.MoveNext());

                    return result;
              }
         }
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

It is clear that if `source` implements `IList` then `source` is not enumerated and therefore your assumption that this is a "bug" in Resharper is correct.

I'd consider it more like a false positive probably due to the fact that Resharper has no general way to know that `Last()`'s implementation avoids unnecessary enumerations. It is probably deciding to flag the potential multiple enumeration based on the fact that `Last<TSource>` is defined for typed `IEnumerable<T>` objects.

Comment: I did a test. Have a look at the screen shot. Resharper is capable of understanding the difference.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Have you tried seeing if Resharper flags that same code when passing an `IEnumerable`? I don't see that code being a repro exactly equivalent to your original issue.

Comment: Yeah it does. I tried passing an IEnumerable and it flags it. Swap it with a List and it doesn't flag it.

Comment: It would flag the multiple enumeration because there _are_ multiple enumerations. The point is that Resharper doesn't usually flag multiple enumerations of List<T> because it knows that an enumeration thereof does not involve an expensive operation such as issuing a database query. AFAIK it just looks at the type of the enumerable, whether there is more than one enumeration of it, and whether there are annotations/attributes it needs to consider. tl;dr There ARE multiple enumerations, but Resharper usually ignores these when the enumerable is of type List<T>.

Comment: @StephenKennedy But that is the point: `First` and `Last` do *not* enumerate. See the implementation, it just returns `list[0]` or `list[count - 1]` when the passed object implements `IList`

Comment: @InBetween Resharper doesn't check the implementation AFAIK. It just see that you are passing the same IEnumerable to a method more than once. I

Comment: I see your point but its probably academic as I doubt Resharper is implementation aware AND it should ignore this issue for List<T> regardless. Point taken though!